# browser_client.dart:98 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/posts 401 (Unauthorized)

Tags: laravel, flutter

I am creating an app that has a login and register page that after i register or login am supposed to be directed to the home screen but immeadiately the app shows the homescreen it redirects back to the login page ...
I am using laravel as my backend and flutter as my frontend
the following are the codes

this is the constant class

````
```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
//___STRINGS_____

//const baseUrl = 'http://10.20.96.143:8000/api';
//const loginUrl = 'http://10.20.96.143:8000/api/login';
const baseUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api';
const loginUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login';
const registerUrl = '$baseUrl/register';
const userUrl = '$baseUrl/user';
const logOutUrl = '$baseUrl/logout';
const postsUrl = '$baseUrl/posts';
const commentsUrl = '$baseUrl/comments';

//______ERRORS___
const serverError = 'Server error';
const unauthorized = 'unauthorized';
const somethingWentWrong = 'something went wrong try again';
```
the post service class

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:blog_project/models/api_response.dart';
import 'package:blog_project/models/post.dart';
import 'package:blog_project/models/user.dart';
import 'package:blog_project/service/constant.dart';
import 'package:blog_project/service/user_service.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

// get all posts
Future<ApiResponse> getPosts() async {
  ApiResponse apiResponse = ApiResponse();
  try {
    String token = await getToken();
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(postsUrl), headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer $token'
    });

    switch (response.statusCode) {
      case 200:
        apiResponse.data = jsonDecode(response.body)['posts']
            .map((p) => Post.fromJson(p))
            .toList();
        // we get list of posts, so we need to map each item to post model
        apiResponse.data as List<dynamic>;
        break;
      case 401:
        apiResponse.error = unauthorized;
        break;
      default:
        apiResponse.error = somethingWentWrong;
        break;
    }
  } catch (e) {
    apiResponse.error = serverError;
  }
  return apiResponse;
}

Future<ApiResponse> createPosts(String body, String? image) async {
  ApiResponse apiResponse = ApiResponse();
  try {
    String token = await getToken();
    final response = await http.post(Uri.parse(postsUrl),
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'Bearer $token'
        },
        body: image != null
            ? {
                'body': body,
                'image': image,
              }
            : {'body': body});

    switch (response.statusCode) {
      case 200:
        apiResponse.data = jsonDecode(response.body);
        break;

      case 422:
        final errors = jsonDecode(response.body)['errors'];
        apiResponse.error = errors[errors.keys.elementAt(0)[0]];
        break;
      case 401:
        apiResponse.error = unauthorized;
        break;
      default:
        apiResponse.error = somethingWentWrong;
        break;
    }
  } catch (e) {
    apiResponse.error = serverError;
  }
  return apiResponse;
}

Future<ApiResponse> editPosts(int postId, String body) async {
  ApiResponse apiResponse = ApiResponse();
  try {
    String token = await getToken();
    final response = await http.put(Uri.parse('$postsUrl/$postId'), headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer $token'
    }, body: {
      'body': body
    });

    switch (response.statusCode) {
      case 200:
        apiResponse.data = jsonDecode(response.body)['message'];
        break;

      case 403:
        apiResponse.error = jsonDecode(response.body)['message'];
        break;
      case 401:
        apiResponse.error = unauthorized;
        break;
      default:
        apiResponse.error = somethingWentWrong;
        break;
    }
  } catch (e) {
    apiResponse.error = serverError;
  }
  return apiResponse;
}

Future<ApiResponse> deletePosts(int postId) async {
  ApiResponse apiResponse = ApiResponse();
  try {
    String token = await getToken();
    final response = await http.delete(Uri.parse('$postsUrl/$postId'),
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'Bearer $token'
        });

    switch (response.statusCode) {
      case 200:
        apiResponse.data = jsonDecode(response.body)['message'];
        break;

      case 403:
        apiResponse.error = jsonDecode(response.body)['message'];
        break;
      case 401:
        apiResponse.error = unauthorized;
        break;
      default:
        apiResponse.error = somethingWentWrong;
        break;
    }
  } catch (e) {
    apiResponse.error = serverError;
  }
  return apiResponse;
}

Future<ApiResponse> likeUnlikePost(int postId) async {
  ApiResponse apiResponse = ApiResponse();
  try {
    String token = await getToken();
    final response = await http.put(Uri.parse('$postsUrl/$postId/likes'),
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'Bearer $token'
        });

    switch (response.statusCode) {
      case 200:
        apiResponse.data = jsonDecode(response.body)['message'];
        break;

      case 401:
        apiResponse.error = unauthorized;
        break;
      default:
        apiResponse.error = somethingWentWrong;
        break;
    }
  } catch (e) {
    apiResponse.error = serverError;
  }
  return apiResponse;
}
```
the user service class
```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:blog_project/models/api_response.dart';
import 'package:blog_project/models/user.dart';
import 'package:blog_project/screens/register.dart';
import 'package:blog_project/service/constant.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

Future<ApiResponse> login(String email, String password) async {
  ApiResponse apiResponse = ApiResponse();
  try {
    final response = await http.post(Uri.parse(loginUrl),
        headers: {'Accept': 'application/json'},
        body: {'email': email, 'password': password});

    switch (response.statusCode) {
      case 200:
        apiResponse.data = User.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
        break;
      case 422:
        final errors = jsonDecode(response.body)['errors'];
        apiResponse.error = errors[errors.keys.elementAt(0)][0];
        break;
      case 403:
        apiResponse.error = jsonDecode(response.body)['message'];
        break;
      default:
        apiResponse.error = somethingWentWrong;
        break;
    }
  } catch (e) {
    apiResponse.error = serverError;
  }
  return apiResponse;
}

// register
Future<ApiResponse> register(String name, String email, String password) async {
  ApiResponse apiResponse = ApiResponse();
  try {
    final response = await http.post(Uri.parse(registerUrl), headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json'
    }, body: {
      'name': name,
      'email': email,
      'password': password,
      'password_confirmation': password
    });
    // final response =
    //     await http.post(Uri.parse(RegisterUrl(email, name, password)));
    // print(jsonDecode(response.body)['errors']);
    switch (response.statusCode) {
      case 200:
        apiResponse.data = User.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
        break;
      case 422:
        final errors = jsonDecode(response.body)['errors'];
        apiResponse.error = errors[errors.keys.elementAt(0)][0];
        break;

      default:
        apiResponse.error = somethingWentWrong;
        break;
    }
  } catch (e) {
    apiResponse.error = serverError;
  }
  return apiResponse;
}

//user
Future<ApiResponse> getUserDetail() async {
  ApiResponse apiResponse = ApiResponse();
  try {
    String token = await getToken();
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(userUrl), headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer $token'
    });

    switch (response.statusCode) {
      case 200:
        apiResponse.data = User.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
        break;
      case 401:
        apiResponse.error = unauthorized;
        break;
      default:
        apiResponse.error = somethingWentWrong;
        break;
    }
  } catch (e) {
    apiResponse.error = serverError;
  }
  return apiResponse;
}

//update user
Future<ApiResponse> updateUser(String name, String? image) async {
  ApiResponse apiResponse = ApiResponse();
  try {
    String token = await getToken();
    final response = await http.put(Uri.parse(userUrl),
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'Bearer $token'
        },
        body: image == null
            ? {
                'name': name,
              }
            : {'name': name, 'image': image});
    // user can update his/her name or name and image

    switch (response.statusCode) {
      case 200:
        apiResponse.data = jsonDecode(response.body)['message'];
        break;
      case 401:
        apiResponse.error = unauthorized;
        break;
      default:
        print(response.body);
        apiResponse.error = somethingWentWrong;
        break;
    }
  } catch (e) {
    apiResponse.error = serverError;
  }
  return apiResponse;
}

//getToken
Future<String> getToken() async {
  SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  return pref.getString("token") ?? '';
}

//getUserId
Future<int> getUserId() async {
  SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  return pref.getInt('userId') ?? 0;
}

//getLogOut
Future<bool> logOut() async {
  SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  return await pref.remove('token');
}

//Get base64 ecoded image
String? getStringImage(File? file) {
  if (file == null) return null;
  return base64Encode(file.readAsBytesSync());
}
```
post class
```
import 'package:blog_project/models/api_response.dart';
import 'package:blog_project/models/post.dart';
import 'package:blog_project/screens/comments_screen.dart';
import 'package:blog_project/screens/login.dart';
import 'package:blog_project/screens/postForm.dart';
import 'package:blog_project/service/constant.dart';
import 'package:blog_project/service/post_service.dart';
import 'package:blog_project/service/user_service.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class PostScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const PostScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<PostScreen> createState() => _PostScreenState();
}

class _PostScreenState extends State<PostScreen> {
  List<dynamic> _postList = [];
  int userId = 0;
  bool _loading = true;

  Future<void> retrievePosts() async {
    userId = await getUserId();
    ApiResponse response = await getPosts();
    if (response.error == null) {
      setState(() {
        _postList = response.data as List<dynamic>;
        _loading = _loading ? !_loading : _loading;
      });
    } else if (response.error == unauthorized) {
      logOut().then((value) => Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Login()), (route) => false));
    } else {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
          .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('$response.error')));
    }
  }

  //post Like or Dislike
  void _handlePostLikeDislike(int postId) async {
    ApiResponse response = await likeUnlikePost(postId);
    if (response.error == null) {
      retrievePosts();
    } else if (response.error == unauthorized) {
      logOut().then((value) => {
            Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Login()),
                (route) => false)
          });
    } else {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
        content: Text('${response.error}'),
      ));
    }
  }

  void _handleDeletePost(int postId) async {
    ApiResponse response = await deletePosts(postId);
    if (response.error == null) {
      retrievePosts();
    } else if (response.error == unauthorized) {
      logOut().then((value) => {
            Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Login()),
                (route) => false)
          });
    } else {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
        content: Text('${response.error}'),
      ));
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    retrievePosts();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _loading
        ? const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
        : RefreshIndicator(
            onRefresh: () {
              return retrievePosts();
            },
            child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: _postList.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  Post post = _postList[index];
                  //return Text('${post.body}');
                  return Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          horizontal: 4, vertical: 10),
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children: [
                              Padding(
                                padding:
                                    const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 6),
                                child: Row(
                                  children: [
                                    Container(
                                        width: 38,
                                        height: 38,
                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                            image: post.user!.image != null
                                                ? DecorationImage(
                                                    image: NetworkImage(
                                                        '${post.user!.image}'))
                                                : null,
                                            borderRadius:
                                                BorderRadius.circular(25),
                                            color: Colors.amber)),
                                    const SizedBox(
                                      width: 10,
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      '${post.user!.name}',
                                      style: const TextStyle(
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                        fontSize: 17,
                                      ),
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                              post.user!.id == userId
                                  ? PopupMenuButton(
                                      child: const Padding(
                                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
                                          child: Icon(
                                            Icons.more_vert,
                                            color: Colors.black,
                                          )),
                                      itemBuilder: (context) => [
                                        const PopupMenuItem(
                                          child: Text('edit'),
                                          value: 'edit',
                                        ),
                                        const PopupMenuItem(
                                            child: Text('delete'),
                                            value: 'delete')
                                      ],
                                      onSelected: (val) {
                                        if (val == 'edit') {
                                          Navigator.of(context).push(
                                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                                  builder: (context) =>
                                                      PostForm(
                                                        title: 'Edit Post',
                                                        post: post,
                                                      )));
                                        } else {
                                          _handleDeletePost(post.id ?? 0);
                                        }
                                      },
                                    )
                                  : const SizedBox()
                            ],
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(
                            height: 12,
                          ),
                          Text('${post.body}'),
                          post.image != null
                              ? Container(
                                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                                  height: 180,
                                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      image: DecorationImage(
                                          image: NetworkImage('${post.image}'),
                                          fit: BoxFit.cover)),
                                )
                              : SizedBox(height: post.image != null ? 0 : 10),
                          Row(
                            children: [
                              kLikeAndComment(
                                  post.likesCount ?? 0,
                                  post.selfLiked == true
                                      ? Icons.favorite
                                      : Icons.favorite_outlined,
                                  post.selfLiked == true
                                      ? Colors.red
                                      : Colors.black38,
                                  () {}),
                              Container(
                                height: 25,
                                width: 0.5,
                                color: Colors.black38,
                              ),
                              kLikeAndComment(post.commentsCount ?? 0,
                                  Icons.sms_outlined, Colors.black54, () {
                                Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) =>
                                        const CommentScreen()));
                              })
                            ],
                          ),
                          Container(
                              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                              height: 0.5,
                              color: Colors.black26)
                        ],
                      ));
                }));
  }
}```

this is the laravel controller class
```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\post;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class postController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return response([
            'posts' => post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                ->with('user:id,image,name')
                ->withCount('comments', 'likes')->with('likes', function ($like) {
                    return $like->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->
                        select('id', 'post_id', 'user_id')->get();
                })->get()
        ], 200);
    }



    public function show($id)
    {
        return response(['post' => post::where('id', $id)->withCount('likes', 'comments')->get()], 200);
    }

    //create a post
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $attrs = $request->validate([
            'body' => 'required|string',
        ]);

        $image = $this->saveImage($request->image, 'posts');


        //if (auth()->check()) {
        //    $user_id = auth()->user()->id;
        // $post = post::create([
        //    'body' => $attrs['body'],
        //    'user_id' => $user_id,
        //     'image' => $image,
        // ]);



        $post = post::create([
            'body' => $attrs['body'],
            'user_id' => auth()->user()->id,
            'image' => $image,
        ]);


        return response([
            'message' => 'post created',
            'post' => $post
        ], 200);
    }
    //else {
    //   return response([
    //         'message' => 'Unauthorized. Please log in to create a post.'
    //   ], 401);
    // }


    //}


    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $post = post::find($id);
        if (!$post) {
            return response([
                'message' => 'not found'
            ], 403);
        }

        if ($post->user_id != auth()->user()->id) {
            return response([
                'message' => 'permission denied'
            ], 403);
        }

        $attrs = $request->validate([
            'body' => 'required|string',
        ]);

        $post->update([
            'body' => $attrs['body']
        ]);


        return response([
            'message' => 'post updated',
            'post' => $post
        ], 200);
    }

    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $post = post::find($id);
        if (!$post) {
            return response([
                'message' => 'not found'
            ], 403);
        }

        if ($post->user_id != auth()->user()->id) {
            return response([
                'message' => 'permission denied'
            ], 403);
        }

        $post->coments()->delete();
        $post->like()->delete();
        $post->delete();

        return response([
            'message' => 'post deleted',
        ], 200);

    }
}





```
````

Comment: Please check 'Authorization': 'Bearer $token' line of code. Change it to 'Authorization': 'Bearer '. $token ... I Mean treat it as a string concat of str and a variable. Be careful, there is a space after the word Bearer.